# ActionScript3 Image Morph/Warp

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on an application in actionscript 3

and I need some script to produce effects on images, especially pictures of faces

similar to these:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.andhat.FunnyFaceFree

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: hello, I need warp face images, just like in this link: http://www.connectedpixel.com/blog/sites/default/files/flash/morph/animmorph.swf

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use displacement maps. There are tons of tutorials that can be found on Google.

Comment: Hello, I'm looking for two days on google, and - although I found information - can not find a way. That's why I'm asking in this forum. If I already knew how to use tons of tutorials would not be asking this. Can you recommend some example code? Thank you.

Comment: Check out the second example. http://www.andysaia.com/radicalpropositions/displacement-maps-in-as3/ (this was the first google result)